# Rearrange MySQL table from each month

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my target table

```
retail_id   month   tgt_volume   product_type
1         2013-11-01    2        Bar
2         2013-10-01    1        Touch
3         2013-09-01    1        Bar
4         2013-10-01    5        Smart
5         2013-10-01    8        Bar
3         2013-08-01    2        Smart
2         2013-08-01    5        Bar
3         2013-07-01    7        Bar
3         2013-07-01    2        Smart
```

I need this format

```
retail_id  bar  smart   touch   total   month
1           2    0       0       2       2013-11-01
2           0    0       1       1       2013-10-01     
2           5    0       0       5       2013-08-01
3           1    0       0       1       2013-09-01 
3           0    2       0       2       2013-08-01 
3           7    2       0       9       2013-07-01
4           0    5       0       5       2013-08-01
5           8    0       0       8       2013-10-01
```

So I want to retrieve every months total target and each product type total for each `retail_id`. I was trying a query which count every `product_type` but not count each month. How can I do this to make above format.. my test query is(without month count)

```
SELECT   DISTINCT t.retail_id,bar_vol.bar,smart_vol.smart,touch_vol.touch,total.total,t.month FROM targets t
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(tgt_volume) AS bar,retail_id FROM targets t1 WHERE t1.product_type='Bar' GROUP BY retail_id) AS bar_vol  
ON  t.retail_id=bar_vol.retail_id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(tgt_volume) AS smart,retail_id FROM targets t2 WHERE t2.product_type='Smart' GROUP BY retail_id) AS smart_vol  
ON  t.retail_id=smart_vol.retail_id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(tgt_volume) AS touch,retail_id FROM targets t3 WHERE t3.product_type='Touch' GROUP BY retail_id) AS touch_vol  
ON  t.retail_id=touch_vol.retail_id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SUM(tgt_volume) AS total,retail_id FROM targets t4  GROUP BY retail_id) AS total  
ON  t.retail_id=total.retail_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement inside an aggregate function to achieve this:

```
SELECT  Retail_ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN product_Type = 'Bar' THEN tgt_Volume ELSE 0 END) AS Bar,
        SUM(CASE WHEN product_Type = 'smart' THEN tgt_Volume ELSE 0 END) AS Smart,
        SUM(CASE WHEN product_Type = 'Touch' THEN tgt_Volume ELSE 0 END) AS Touch,
        SUM(tgt_Volume) AS Total,
        Month
FROM    targets 
GROUP BY RetailId, Month;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bd0c84/1)**

Comment: Thank. But if I insert an other retail_id in a common month. it doesn't show correct data. For example if I insert (2, '2013-07-01', 7, 'Bar') then  2013-07-01 month should 2 rows for 2 & 3 retail_id. please view your [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bd0c84/1) again

Comment: @GarethD . . . I changed your query to group by both `Retail_Id` and `Month`, because I think that is what the OP is looking for.